# SharePoint Designer workflow start at specific date/time

Tags: 2007, workflow

Is it possible to start a workflow I've designed in SPD 2007 to start at a particular date/time?

Specifically I want to start the workflow on the 1st of November every year. Is this possible to do without writing code?

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workflow needs to run from a specific event on a list... So i think it is impossible.  You could start with code, through a timer job.

Comment: Thanks, the timer job looks like the way to go in this instance. Otherwise its setting a Pause until date action when every list item is created which seems too heavy.